# What user image is appropriate for a StackOverflow, or StackExchange site?

Tags: discussion

Is it arrogant to set your user image to that of a book you appreciate or admire, but never wrote yourself?

How about a parody or creative work based on that book image?

I debated putting this on meta, but think this is a very subjective question that applies to more than one site, so I think this is an appropriate here or on programmers.stackexchange.com.  I'm interested in where the community decides to put this one....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as it is a [PG-13](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motion_Picture_Association_of_America_film_rating_system#The_PG-13_rating_is_adopted) or better image, then it's probably fine.

> Rated PG-13: Parents are strongly cautioned to give special guidance for attendance of children under 13 - Some material may be inappropriate for young children

Comment: hmm... "or better" is subject to interpretation. ;)